# What is the unicode character for the close symbol used by Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: unicode, twitter-bootstrap

Just curious, because I just realized it wasn't an actual "x" (annoying how long that took to figure out).

Comment: Nice @InsaneSkull, even better: &#215;

Comment: I saw plenty of other questions like this one on the network and theyre all "on hold" cause theyre "opinion based".. Shouldnt this one receive the same treatment?

Comment: I haven't seen the other questions, so I can't speak about them, but this one is definitely not opinion based. There's a completely objective answer to this question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It uses `×`.

You can use the following to obtain the desired information about any character:

```
$ perl -Mcharnames=:full -CA -e'
   printf("U+%04X %s\n", $_, charnames::viacode($_))
      for unpack "W*", $ARGV[0];
' ×
U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN
```

If you're going to use it in HTML, you can encode it as follows:

```
$ perl -MHTML::Entities -CA -e'
   CORE::say encode_entities($ARGV[0]);
' ×
&times;
```

---

Notes:

- The above programs expect the argument to be encoded using UTF-8.
- The line breaks can be removed to make true one-liners.

Comment: Please use pseudo code so we could understand the answer

Comment: @Pauli Sudarshan Terho, The first program outputs the number (U+00D7) and the name (MULTIPLICATION SIGN) of the code point. The second, an HTML entity that resolves to it. I'm not sure how someone could think something different.

Comment: I don't think Twitter is implemented in Perl. Your code does not proove it is the same unicode that Twitter use.

Comment: @Pauli Sudarshan Terho, It doesn't need to. I provided the character, I gave information about the character, and I showed how to obtain it for other characters in the process. (And I've just updated it to work for an entire strings in addition to single characters.) That goes above and beyond what the OP asked for.

Comment: I can not find any example to confirm the character, how do you know it is &time; ? Twitter Bootstrap is written in JS, not Perl. Examples has no &times; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples

Answer (score 282):

The multiplication sign ( × ) was a bit too small for what I wanted and increasing the font size broke other things, so I found these larger alternatives:

✕ [Multiplication X](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2715/index.htm) (U+2715)

- Decimal HTML entity: `&#10005;`
- Hex HTML entity: `&#x2715;`

✖ [Heavy Multiplication X](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2716/index.htm) (U+2716)

- Decimal HTML entity: `&#10006;`
- Hex HTML entity: `&#x2716;`

❌ [Cross Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/274c/index.htm) (U+274C)

- Decimal HTML entity: `&#10060;`
- Hex HTML entity: `&#x274c;`

I hope these will save somebody some time.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to use Unicode, you can simply use the HTML character entity `&times;`.

Answer (score 5):

right answer today: `&times;`
used in close buttons

Answer (score 4):

Instead of giving you fish I will give you dynamite.
When working online if you need to figure out what Unicode specific character is you can use following javascript (you might also need to add .val() or .text() or [0] after selector dependent on situation):

```
$('yourTextselector').charCodeAt(0).toString(16) // charCodeAt is the position of character in text you selected.
```

**Example:**

```
"ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้".charCodeAt(2).toString(16)
```

returns `"e49"`

which means that it's `\u0e49` since leading zeroes get 'swallowed'.

This should help you identify other characters that look similar but are in fact different

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have your answer, here is an additional helpful trick when working with Unicode on Windows OS.

1. Open up *Wordpad*
2. Type in the Unicode value such as **2715**
3. With cursor next to what you typed, press **ALT+X** on the keyboard.

It will show the visual representation of that character.  This trick works in reverse as well.  If you do a copy and paste of the visual representation and then hit ALT+X it will show you the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed ❎ that looks nice, but display in green only into *Firefox*.

A possible workaround to adjust that is to use [css filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Inspect the element to get the filter values.

```js
adjustHUE.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  document.querySelector("#close").style.cssText += "filter:hue-rotate(" + e.target.value + "deg) brightness(" + adjustBRIGHTNESS.value + ")"
})

adjustBRIGHTNESS.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  document.querySelector("#close").style.cssText += "filter:hue-rotate(" + adjustHUE.value + "deg) brightness(" + e.target.value + ")"
})
```

```css
#close {
  font-size: 6rem;
  padding: 0 2rem 
}
```

```html
<div id="close" style="filter:hue-rotate(0deg)">❎</div>
Hue:<br>
<input id="adjustHUE" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0"><br>
Brightness:<br>
<input id="adjustBRIGHTNESS" type="range" min="0.2" max="1" step="0.01" value="1"><br>
<div id="out"></div>
```

---

From css, this may look like:

```css
span {
  font-size: 2rem;
  z-index: 2;
  filter: hue-rotate(277deg) brightness(0.96);
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<span>❎</span>
```