# Pure css close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/)

Is there any way to make something like the X on that link with pure css?

[image]

Comment: CSS3 has round borders, so "maybe". Creating the X would depend on the presence of an appropriate font.

Comment: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: I must admit that with the introduction of font-awesome, this has all become less important now... no need for 10000+ images anymore, one font file and you're covered.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I spent more time on this than I should have, and haven't tested in IE for obvious reasons. That being said, it's pretty much identical.

http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/14/

```
a.boxclose{
    float:right;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-right:-30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #605F61;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 11px 3px;       
}

.boxclose:before {
    content: "×";
}
```

Comment: I would add -moz-border-radius to support firefox

Comment: @binarious well if you want to support FF <4 you should?

Comment: @Ozzy That version has been deprecated for quite a while. I see less than 0.1% of browser traffic coming from <4.

Comment: @MikeRobinson It's actually closer to 2% and it doesn't harm to add the extra line of code http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php?year=2012&month=6

Comment: why did you show june's statistics in your link in august you cherry picked the link, not that it matters, now the firefox 3 useage is negligible and nickel and dining lines of code to support browsers can hurt you if it affects load time enough and more so if it affects the date you can realease your code because you are spending your time supporting outdated browsers

Comment: @Shawn I spent all of 3 seconds finding that link. Honestly if people want to support older browsers they're welcome to add in the required fields; my solution is simply a solution for current browsers.

Comment: I just noticed you are using the unicode multiplication × `content: "×";` (equivalent to `content: "\00d7"`) instead of x/X. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17622391/436776 mentions other alternatives ✕ ✖ ❌ which may look better (but you would need to check your choice doesn't appear as ▯ depending on font, browser, and device).

Comment: Do you allow us to use it?

Answer (score 46):

My attempt at a close icon, no text

```css
.close-icon
{
  display:block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:red;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%);
  background-color:red;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="close-icon"></a>
```

Comment: How would i do just an X (not the circle background and color background)

Comment: @user3808307, change the `background` line with linear gradient (replace the white color with whatever you need) and remove the other properties that create the circle (background-color, border-radius, border-width, border-style, border-color, box-shadow)

Comment: This is the craziest but also the best solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I become frustrated trying to implement something that looked consistent in all browsers and went with an svg button which can be styled with css.

**html**

```
<svg>
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="none" d="M6.25,6.25,17.75,17.75" />
    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="none" d="M6.25,17.75,17.75,6.25" />
</svg>
```

**css**

```
svg {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}
svg > circle {
    stroke: black;
    fill: white;
}
svg > path {
    stroke: black;
}
svg:hover > circle {
    fill: red;
}
svg:hover > path {
    stroke: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/purves/5exav2m7/

Answer (score 9):

Basic idea: For the a.boxclose:

```
border-radius: 40px;
width:20px;
height 10px;
background-color: #c0c0c0;
border: 1px solid black;
color: white;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 4px;
```

Adding a "X" to the content of the close box.

http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/1/

Quick and dirty, but works.

Answer (score 6):

Hi you can used this code in pure css

as like this

**css**

```
.arrow {
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
border-radius: 30px;
background: #605F61;
font-size: 31px;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 0px;
padding: 11px 3px;
}
.arrow:before{
 content: "×";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="arrow"> 
</a>
```

​
Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/VzZhU/

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Updated css to match with what you have..

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/xLSLd/24/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span class="close-btn"><a href="#">X</a></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.close-btn {
    border: 2px solid #c2c2c2;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    top: -20px;
    background-color: #605F61;
    left: 198px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.close-btn a {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The disappointing thing here is that the "X" isn't transparent (which is how I would likely create a PNG, at least).

I put together this quick test. 
http://jsfiddle.net/UM3a2/22/embedded/result/ which allows you to color the positive space while leaving the negative space transparent. Since it is made entirely of borders it is easy to color since border-color defaults to the text color.

It doesn't fully support I.E. 8 and earlier (border-radius issues), but it degrades to a square fairly nicely (if you're okay with a square close button).

It also requires two HTML elements since you are only allowed two pseudo elements per selector. I don't know exactly where I learned this, but I think it was in an article by Chris Coyier.

```
<div id="close" class="arrow-t-b">
  Close
  <div class="arrow-l-r"> </div>
</div>

#close {
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #333;
  height: 12px;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 12px;
}
#close:hover {
  color: #39F;
}
.arrow-t-b:after,
.arrow-t-b:before,
.arrow-l-r:after, 
.arrow-l-r:before {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  content: "";
  left: 2px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
.arrow-t-b:after {
  border-top-color: inherit;
}
.arrow-l-r:after {
  border-right-color: inherit;
  left: 4px;
  top: 2px;
}
.arrow-t-b:before {
  border-bottom-color: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
}
.arrow-l-r:before {
  border-left-color: inherit;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: This is good, but it's really difficult to customise, ie making the cross larger or the whole thing.

Comment: @rickibalboa It isn't *really* difficult, but it isn't terribly easy either. It is mostly just another approach to get brain juices flowing.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `close` (or any) button on http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/. It gives you pure css value of button.
 **HTML**

```
<span class="classname hightlightTxt">x</span>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
.hightlightTxt {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.classname {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 3px 24px -1px #fce2c1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 3px 24px -1px #fce2c1;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 3px 24px -1px #fce2c1;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffc477), color-stop(1, #fb9e25) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffc477', endColorstr='#fb9e25');
    background-color:#ffc477;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:20px;
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    text-indent:0px;
    border:1px solid #eeb44f;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:32px;
    line-height:32px;
    width:32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #cc9f52;
}
.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fb9e25), color-stop(1, #ffc477) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fb9e25', endColorstr='#ffc477');
    background-color:#fb9e25;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}</style>
/* This button was generated using CSSButtonGenerator.com */
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought - if you're not targeting IE7, you could get away with [any image being base64-encoded and embedded into css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice). I'm assuming your goal is to avoid an unnecessary http request rather than  to actually make a css button as its own goal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure css, without the letter "x"....

Here are some awesome experimental icons that include an "x" in a circle that is made with CSS: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/

Answer (score 0):

I Think It Is Best!

And Use The Simple JS to make this work.

```
<script>
function privacypolicy(){
    var privacypolicy1 = document.getElementById('privacypolicy');
    var privacypolicy2 = ('display: inline;');
    privacypolicy1.style= privacypolicy2;
}
function hideprivacypolicy(){
    var privacypolicy1 = document.getElementById('privacypolicy');
    var privacypolicy2 = ('display: none;');
    privacypolicy1.style= privacypolicy2;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
            .orthi-textlightbox-background{
                background-color: rgba(30, 23, 23, 0.82);
                font-family: siyam rupali; 
                position: fixed; top:0px; 
                bottom:0px; 
                right:0px; 
                width: 100%; 
                border: none; 
                margin:0; 
                padding:0; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                z-index:999999; 
                height: 100%;
                }

                .orthi-textlightbox-area {
                background-color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                width: 50%;
                left: 300px;
                top: 200px;
                padding: 20px 10px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                }
                .orthi-textlightbox-area-close{
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color:black;
                color: white;
                border-radius: 50%;
                padding: 10px;
                float: right;
                border: 1px solid black;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(33, 157, 216, 0.82);
                margin-top:-30px;
                margin-right:-30px;
                cursor:pointer;
                }
</style>
<button onclick="privacypolicy()">Show Content</button>
<div id="privacypolicy" class="orthi-textlightbox-background" style="display:none;">
<div class="orthi-textlightbox-area">
LOL<button class="orthi-textlightbox-area-close" onclick="hideprivacypolicy()">×</button>
</div>
</div>
```