# How to design below effect in a div without using any Images

Tags: html, css, tooltip

[image]

How can we design tip in bottom just like above without using any images.
Below is my trail code:

```
<div id="coverImageToolTip"><p><font color="white">TIP:</font> UPLOAD YOUR<br/> COVER IMAGE HERE
    <div id="tail1"></div>
    <div id="tail2"></div>

#coverImageToolTip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    background-color: gray;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 20%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}


/* #tail1 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    left:20px;
    width:0;height:0;
    border-color:#a0c7ff transparent transparent transparent;
    border-width:10px;
    border-style:solid;
} */

#tail2 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-18px;
    left:20px;
    width:0;height:0;
    border-color: red transparent transparent  red  ;
    border-width:10px;
    border-style:solid;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal markup version:

### 2024 answer

We can create the tooltip tail with a `conic-gradient()` in the transparent border area underneath. We then use `filter: drop-shadow()` to create the shadow following the whole shape. We set these styles on an absolutely positioned pseudo behind the tooltip because we don't want the shadow to also be applied on the close button.

Note that the little bit of JS included only serves to close the tooltip upon clicking the close button.

```js
/* just to close tooltip from button */
addEventListener('click', e => {
  let _t = e.target;
    
  if(_t.getAttribute('aria-label') === 'close') {
    _t.parentNode.classList.add('closed')
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap');

html, body, button { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body { background: radial-gradient(at 0 100%, #dedede, 85%, #165a9b) }

.tooltip {
  --r: 5px; /* tooltip corner rounding */
  --h: 1.25em; /* arrow height */
  --c: #999; /* tooltip background */
  place-self: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: var(--h); /* reserve arrow space */
  padding: .25em;
  width: 8em;
  font: 700 2em/ 1.375 oswald, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    
  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: calc(-1*var(--h));
      /* increase background area with transparent border */
    border: solid var(--h) #0000;
    border-radius: calc(var(--h) + var(--r));
    background: 
      /* main box, restricted to padding-box */
      linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) padding-box, 
      /* tooltip tail, within all border-box */
      conic-gradient(
          from 20deg /* tail start angle */ 
          at 43% /* horizontal tail tip position */ 100%, 
          var(--c) 30deg /* angular size of tail */, #0000 0%) 
        0 100% /* place at the bottom *// 
        50% 50% no-repeat  /* limit size & repetition so no overflow */
        border-box;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 6px #434343);
    content: ''
  }
}

.closed { display: none }

.highlight { color: #fff }

/* prettify close button from here on */
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1.125em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: solid 4px currentcolor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  translate: 50% -50%;
  background: #030303;
  color: var(--c);
  font: inherit;
    
  &::before, &::after {
    grid-area: 1/ 1;
    place-self: center;
    width: .625em; height: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    rotate: -45deg;
    background: currentcolor;
    content: ''
  }
    
  &::after { rotate: 45deg }
}
```

```html
<div class='tooltip'>
  <span class='highlight'>tip:</span> upload your cover image here
  <button aria-label='close'></button>
<div>
```

If the tail jaggedness is disturbing, we can smooth it out with a custom SVG `filter` before the `drop-shadow()` one.

```js
addEventListener('click', e => {
  let _t = e.target;
    
  if(_t.getAttribute('aria-label') === 'close') {
    _t.parentNode.classList.add('closed')
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap');

html, body, button { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body { background: radial-gradient(at 0 100%, #dedede, 85%, #165a9b) }

svg[height='0'] { position: fixed; }

.tooltip {
  --r: 5px; /* tooltip corner rounding */
  --h: 1.25em; /* arrow height */
  --c: #999; /* tooltip background */
  place-self: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: var(--h); /* reserve arrow space */
  padding: .25em;
  width: 8em;
  font: 700 2em/ 1.375 oswald, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    
  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: calc(-1*var(--h));
      /* increase background area with transparent border */
    border: solid var(--h) #0000;
    border-radius: calc(var(--h) + var(--r));
    background: 
      /* main box, restricted to padding-box */
      linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) padding-box, 
      /* tooltip tail, within all border-box */
      conic-gradient(
          from 20deg /* tail start angle */ 
          at 50% /* horizontal tail tip position */ 100%, 
          var(--c) 35deg /* angular size of tail */, #0000 0%) 
        0 100% /* place at the bottom *// 
        100% 50% no-repeat  /* limit size & repetition so no overflow */
        border-box;
    filter: blur(2px) url(#smooth) drop-shadow(0 6px #434343);
    content: ''
  }
}

.closed { display: none }

.highlight { color: #fff }

/* prettify close button from here on */
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1.125em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: solid 4px currentcolor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  translate: 50% -50%;
  background: #030303;
  color: var(--c);
  font: inherit;
    
  &::before, &::after {
    grid-area: 1/ 1;
    place-self: center;
    width: .625em; height: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    rotate: -45deg;
    background: currentcolor;
    content: ''
  }
    
  &::after { rotate: 45deg }
}
```

```html
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <filter id='smooth' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'>
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type='gamma' amplitude='4' exponent='3' offset='-.5'>
    </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</svg>

<div class='tooltip'>
  <span class='highlight'>tip:</span> upload your cover image here
  <button aria-label='close'></button>
<div>
```

### original answer, preserved for web history reasons:

```css
body { background: lightblue; }
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: .5em .2em;
  width: 10.5em; height: 3em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  box-shadow: 0 .2em 0 black;
  background: #999;
  font: 700 1.6em/1.5 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -.75em; right: -.75em;
  border: solid .2em;
  width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: #999;
  font: 900 .65em/1 sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.tooltip:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 25%; bottom: -.75em;
  width: 2em; height: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 .35em 0 black;
  transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.highlight { color: white; }
.highlight:after, .highlight:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; right: 31.025%;
  width: 1.725em; height: .2em;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  background: #999;
  content: '';
}
.highlight:after {
  right: 30.65%;
  transform: skewX(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='tooltip'>
  <span class='highlight'>tip:</span> upload your cover image here
  <button aria-label='close'>x</button>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please see [Pure css close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019797/pure-css-close-button) ( the close button in CSS ) and http://v2.desandro.com/resources/css-speech-bubble-icon/ for the actual trail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the close button and arrow in css but shadow for arrow is not possible.

Look at the code below

**HTML**

```
    <div id="coverImageToolTip">
    <div class="close"><a href="#">X</a></div>
    <p>
    <font color="white">TIP:</font> UPLOAD YOUR<br/> COVER IMAGE HERE
    </p>
    <div id="tail1"></div>
    <div id="tail2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
      .close a{
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px; top:-8px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:black;
    padding:2px 6px;
    color:white;
    border:solid grey 3px;
    border-radius:22px;
    font-size:12px; 
    text-decoration:none
}
        #tail2 {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:-19px;
            left:80px;
            width:0;height:0;
            border-color: grey transparent transparent  grey  ;
            border-width:10px;
            border-style:solid;
            transform:rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
            -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FgdSE/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for your code and I have placed another arrow with shadow(black) color and placed below the gray color arrow and it given me shadow effect..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before` and `after` to simulate a shape close to your image for the arrow. Have a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j34um/3/