# X close button only using css

Tags: css, button

How to make a cross (X) only in CSS3, to use as a close button?

I've been searching for a long time, and cannot found how....
When I look at source code on a website using it, there's always something weird which makes the code I take unusable.

The X button I want: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

When you click an image, this is the cross on the right:

[image]

I think this would be great if somebody can post a simple universal CSS code to make a simple X cross in CSS3.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019797/pure-css-close-button

Comment: you can use fontawesome..

Comment: CSS is really *really* the wrong tool for this job. Just about anything else would be better. A font with the appropriate glyph, an image, SVG, Canvas, anything. But not CSS.

Comment: thx for your answers, but my question wasn't 'is it a good practice', or 'what can replace css to do it (fontawesome)', i wanted to know if someone have the css-only code to put a X close button (as we can see on codrop's link).

Adding content: 'x' on stylesheet is not what i want do beacause the X cross will depend too much on the font-family used. 
I want to make it with pure css shapping.

Comment: i've posted an answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019797/pure-css-close-button/20139794#20139794,

my code doesn't use any text only css

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Main point you are looking for is:

```
.tag-remove::before {
  content: 'x'; // here is your X(cross) sign.
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

FYI, you can make a close button by yourself very easily:

```css
#mdiv {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mdiv {
  height: 25px;
  width: 2px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  Z-index: 1;
}

.md {
  height: 25px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  Z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="mdiv">
  <div class="mdiv">
    <div class="md"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding content: 'x' on stylesheet is not what i want do beacause the X cross will depend too much on the font-family used. I want to make it with pure css shapping.

Comment: @user2746369: please check the edit. is it you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what i was searching for!

thanks lot

Comment: You may to use × (times symbol) instead "X".

Comment: Warning: do not use first example, as using letter X for close symbol is wrong. There is better alternative, that looks much better, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262158/2676137

Comment: This is still problematic. The times symbol renders differently in terms of vertical alignment across different browsers.

Answer (score 100):

As a **pure CSS** solution for the close or 'times' symbol you can use the ISO code with the **content** property. I often use this for :after or :before pseudo selectors.

The content code is **\00d7**.

***Example***

```
div:after{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\00d7"; /* This will render the 'X' */
}
```

You can then style and position the pseudo selector in any way you want.
Hope this helps someone :).

Comment: The "plus" symbol is code `\002b` if anyone is wants that.

Comment: Do you know how to call a function on click of content in angular? Say I want to close the div.. is that possible?

Comment: Another way to do this is to use the **&times;** html symbol in your html, and then style it accordingly... Like so: `<a href="#" class="close-button">&times;</a>` and CSS `.close-button { color: red; }`

Answer (score 72):

Try This [Cross In CSS](https://codepen.io/brissmyr/pen/egidw)

```css
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="close">
```

Comment: could you please explain how your code works? I am struggling to understand form where the `X` is coming from? It seems that the `content=''`plus height and width are doing the trick but I am unable to understand the logic

Comment: I suppose I got it. I didn't know that a pseudo element is actually an element in itself and like all elements, has a box around it. So you are setting width, height of the box. As width is 2px, it effectively creates a bar like 'I'. You could leave the content property empty and just treat the pseudo-element like a content-less box

Comment: Yes this X come from this line  if you know css well plz inspect it and check it out these  how work.if you have still confusion let me know                                                                                           .close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

Comment: Plz inspect this code and check it out thoroughly you get to know how this code made with that

Answer (score 22):

```css
.close-btn {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
```

Comment: So much shorter and easier than the answers above!

Answer (score 21):

Here's some variety for you with several sizes and hover animations.. [demo(link)](http://codepen.io/dcdev/full/izvlh/)

[image]

```
<ul>
  <li>Large</li>
  <li>Medium</li>
  <li>Small</li>
  <li>Switch</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="ele">
    <div class="x large"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x spin large"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x spin large slow"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x flop large"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x t large"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x shift large"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
  </li>
  <li class="ele">
    <div class="x medium"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x spin medium"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x spin medium slow"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x flop medium"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x t medium"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x shift medium"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>

  </li>
  <li class="ele">
    <div class="x small"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x spin small"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x spin small slow"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x flop small"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x t small"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x shift small"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
    <div class="x small grow"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>

  </li>
  <li class="ele">
    <div class="x switch"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.ele div.x {
-webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
}

.ele div.x.slow {
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
  transition-duration:1s;
}

ul { list-style:none;float:left;display:block;width:100%; }
li { display:inline;width:25%;float:left; }
.ele { width:25%;display:inline; }
.x {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#CCC;
  border-radius:2px;
  border:solid 2px #FFF;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.x.large { 
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

.x.medium {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}

.x.small {
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}

.x.switch {
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
}
.x.grow {

}

.x.spin:hover{
  background:#BB3333;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.x.flop:hover{
  background:#BB3333;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.x.t:hover{
  background:#BB3333;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.x.shift:hover{
  background:#BB3333;
}

.x b{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.x.small b {
  border:solid 5px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.x.medium b {
  border:solid 10px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.x.large b {
  border:solid 15px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.x.switch b {
  border:solid 10px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.x b:nth-child(1){
  border-top-color:#FFF;
  top:-2px;
}
.x b:nth-child(2){
  border-left-color:#FFF;
  left:-2px;
}
.x b:nth-child(3){
  border-bottom-color:#FFF;
  bottom:-2px;
}
.x b:nth-child(4){
  border-right-color:#FFF;
  right:-2px;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

## -- Simple HTML Solution --

Final result of easy to resize icon:

[image: two close X buttons with different thickness.]

JSfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/allenski/yr5gk3cm/

The simple HTML:

```html
<a href="#" class="close" tabindex="0" role="button">close</a>
```

> Note:
>
> - `tabindex` attribute is there to help accessibility focus of iOS touch devices.
> - `role` attribute is to let screen readers users know this is a button.
> - The word `close` is also intended for screen readers to mention.

The CSS code:

```css
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.close:before, 
.close:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    content: '';
}
.close:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

To adjust thickness of close X icon, change the `width` property. Example for thinner icon:

```css
.close:before, 
.close:after {
    width: 2px;
}
```

To adjust length of close X icon, change the `height` property. Example:

```css
.close:before, 
.close:after {
    height: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use svg.

```html
<svg viewPort="0 0 12 12" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line x1="1" y1="11" 
          x2="11" y2="1" 
          stroke="black" 
          stroke-width="2"/>
    <line x1="1" y1="1" 
          x2="11" y2="11" 
          stroke="black" 
          stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Make sure to use [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox), not `viewPort`. This is what I'm currently using: `<svg class="close" viewBox="0 0 1 1" height="1" width="1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><line x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" /><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" /></svg>`.

Answer (score 4):

**True CSS with proper semantic and accessibility settings.**

**It is a `<button>`, It has text for screen readers.**

https://codepen.io/specialweb/pen/ExyWPYv?editors=1100

```css
button {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0;
}

button::before,
button::after {
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
}

button::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0px);
}


/* demo */
body {
  background: black;
}
.pane {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pane">
  <button type="button"><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good drop-in solution for perfectly centered circular X icon buttons

- Using only CSS
- Not relying on a font
- The thickness and length of the tines of the X can be configured without affecting centering, using `width` and `height` in the pseudo element rule `.close::before, .close::after`
- Screen reader support using `aria-label`
- Works on a light or dark background by using transparent grays and `currentColor` to adapt to the current text color specified on the button or an ancestor.

```css
.close {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.close:focus,
.close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
.close:active {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
}
/* tines of the X */
.close::before,
.close::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: currentColor;
}
.close::before {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.close::after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 15px">
    <button class="close" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
<div style="background: black; color: white; padding: 15px">
    <button class="close" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
<div style="background: orange; color: yellow; padding: 15px">
    <button class="close" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; position: relative; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
   <div style="width: 1.5px; height: 100%; background-color: #9c9f9c; position: absolute; transform: rotate(45deg); border-radius: 2px;"></div>
   <div style="width: 1.5px; height: 100%; background-color: #9c9f9c; position: absolute; transform: rotate(-45deg); border-radius: 2px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use two divs that you style as strokes and then rotate with +/- 45%.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}
.close {
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    z-index:1;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
  background: green;
  position:relative;  
}
.close span{
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:3px;
    left:10%;
    top:45%;
    background-color: black;
}

.first {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.last {
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="close">
  <span class="first"></span>
  <span class="last"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.class a::after {
    content: " x";
    font-size: 8px;
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following Zubair Saif's answer, I created it in css-in-js for my use case. I'm adding it here if it helps someone :

```js
closeButton: {
      position: "absolute",
      right: "32px",
      width: "32px",
      height: "32px",
      opacity: "0.3",
      "&:hover": {
        opacity: 1,
      },
      "&:before": {
        position: "absolute",
        left: "15px",
        content: '""',
        height: "33px",
        width: "2px",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        transform: "rotate(45deg)",
      },
      "&:after": {
        position: "absolute",
        left: "15px",
        content: '""',
        height: "33px",
        width: "2px",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        transform: "rotate(-45deg)",
      }
```

You'll note the difference in the `content` prop (it doesn't work with the regular `" "`)

Comment: This is not CSS. Is it SCSS, or LESS or something? Should make it clear.

Comment: It's css-in-js, as stated in my answer.