# Partial "X" shape over image on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, css-shapes

I need a sort of **X shape over an image on hover**. But not the whole "X", just the outer bits. This is the image from my designer:

[image: partial X shape over image]

I've got a nice "X" shape on hover here:

```css
#xdiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}
#xdiv:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .4;
}
#xdiv:hover .xdiv1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1;
}
#xdiv:hover .xdiv2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="xdiv">
  <div class="xdiv1">
    <div class="xdiv2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That I modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18611371/2856569).

Going by my designer's example, is this possible using CSS and not using another image on hover?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can achieve the partial X shape with:

- 2 pseudo elements instead of divs to reduce markup
- top/bottom borders and no background so the middle part of the shape is transparent

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/atw6eguy/5/)**

*NOTE : you should also declare non prefixed properties after the prefixed ones (transforms in your snippet)*

```css
#xdiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}
#xdiv:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .4;
}
#xdiv:before, #xdiv:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 50%; top: 0;
  width: 1px; height: 100px;
  border-top: 50px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #333;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#xdiv:hover:before {
  display: block;
}
#xdiv:hover:after {
  display: block;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="xdiv"></div>
```

---

Previous answer :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/atw6eguy/3/)**

```css
#xdiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}
#xdiv:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .4;
}
#xdiv:hover .xdiv1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 1px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-top: 50px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #333;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 1;
}
#xdiv:hover .xdiv2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1px;
    border-top: 50px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #333;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="xdiv" >
<div class="xdiv1">
    <div class="xdiv2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've got a small snag. I'm using Bootstrap and adding the Bootstrap CSS completely destroys this "X" hover style. I'm trying to pinpoint exactly what kills it, but it's not immediately obvious :(

Comment: @Jeannie do you have it in a fiddle or somewhere I can look at it?

Comment: Yes, here's your code with Bootstrap CDN added [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/z2vsLdzn/)

Comment: @Jeannie ok it is becasue bootstraps adds `box-sizing:border-box;` property to pseudo elements. You can either change that property to `content-box` on those pseudo elements either change their height to `200px` like this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/z2vsLdzn/2/

Comment: Nice! I thought that was what was happening, but turning it off in dev tools didn't fix it. Thank you so much :D Plus now I better understand how your solution works.

Answer (score 4):

Approach using Gradients:

1. Using a div and background color, I've created the square div

```
+-------------+
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

2. Then, using a pseudo element rotated 45 degrees, and another at -45 degrees,
   You could generate the 'X' shape (currently setting a solid background color for help with positioning):

```
+-------------+
|\           /|
|  \       /  |
|    \   /    |
|      \      |
|     /  \    |
|   /      \  |
| /          \|
+-------------+
```

3. Now, rather than using a solid black colour, you could use a gradient background, with 'color stops' to make the center transparent. (note: for gradients, I would recommend [this generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) )
4. This leaves something like:

```
+-------------+
|\           /|
|  \       /  |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|   /      \  |
| /          \|
+-------------+
```

depending on your positioning of the color stops.

**DEMO**

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  height: 200%;
  width: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  height: 200%;
  width: 2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
div:hover:before, div:hover:after{
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 31%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 69%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(30%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(31%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(69%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(70%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 31%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 69%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @jeannie: wa just posting a different approach (there are others btw). ut for your solution/case, I personally would go for web-tiki's solution

Comment: gotcha and thanks for explaining this solution better.

Answer (score 3):

alternative using box-shadow

```css
div{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
div:before, div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 33.3333333%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
div:before{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 26px;
  left: -6px;
  box-shadow: 13em 0 0;
}
div:after{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: -6px;
  top: 26px;
  box-shadow: -13em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

or

```css
div{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
div:before, div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 33.3333333%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 48px;
}
div:before{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 14px;
  box-shadow: 10em 0 0;
}
div:after{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 14px;
  box-shadow: -10em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```