# Google Maps API Directions - Swap between 2 different sidebars

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

The code below brings up 2 sidebars.  The first sidebar appears when you enter an address and is a listing of title, address and get directions link sorted by actual mileage. When you click one of the get directions links, a second sidebar with directions appears beneath the first sidebar.

I want to change this so when you click one of the get directions links, the first sidebar disappears bringing up the 2nd sidebar with directions only.  There should also be an X to click which takes you back to first sidebar and removes the 2nd sidebar with the directions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       html, body, #map_canvas {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         height: 100%;
         }
     </style>

<style type='text/css'>
.text
{
width:300px;
height:600px;
background-color:white;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     

// Store Name[0],Address[1],Coordinates[2],Icon[3]

var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "145 Rock Ridge Road, Chester, NY ", "41.314926,-74.270134", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],

 ];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
// alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {       
            zoom: 9,       
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),       
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
        });      
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();      
  var marker, i;      
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found "+locations.length+" locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {         
            var coordStr = locations[i][2];
        var coords = coordStr.split(",");
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),parseFloat(coords[1]));
            bounds.extend(pt);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({         
                            position: pt,         
                            map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3],
                            address: locations[i][1],
                            title: locations[i][0],
                            html: locations[i][0]+"<br>"+locations[i][1]+"<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;"+locations[i][1]+"&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
                            });                              
            gmarkers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {         return function() 
            {           infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);         
            }       
        })
        (marker, i));     
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);   

}

      function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
            customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location,12);
            // get driving distance
            closest = closest.splice(0,12);
            calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest,12);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

function findClosestN(pt,numberOfResults) {
   var closest = [];
   document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing "+gmarkers.length+"<br>";
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
     gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt,gmarkers[i].getPosition());
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process "+i+":"+gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+":"+gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2)+"<br>";
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
     closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
     closest.sort(sortByDist);  
   }
   
   return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a,b) { 
 return (a.distance- b.distance)

}
     
function calculateDistances(pt,closest,numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request =    {
      origins: [pt],
      destinations: [],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    };
  for (var i=0; i < closest.length; i++) {
  request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

     var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);

        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + results[i].address + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"

      }
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
      origin:origin,
      destination:destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('side_bar'));
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script> 
   </head>
   <body>
   <table border="0"><tr><td>
     <div id="map" style="height: 600px; width:800px;"></div>
     </td><td>
     <div id="side_bar" class = 'text'> </div>
     </td></tr></table>

<input id="address" type="text" value="Palo Alto, CA"></input>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();"></input>
<div id="info"></div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

This seems to be the code to bring up the first sidebar

```
var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
```

This seems to be the code to bring up the second sidebar.

```
 directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('side_bar'));
```

I wasn't sure how to go about this was looking for something on swapping sidebars or replacing them but couldn't find anything useful.  Could anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. you probably want to make a new element for the directions panel, then move that over the sidebar
2. create an "X" to close it. (I took one from this question: [X close button only using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611195/x-close-button-only-using-css)

CSS for directions panel:

```
#panel {
  z-index: -100;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

CSS for side_bar:

```
#side_bar {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vj0cpv0c/11/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ["John Doe", "145 Rock Ridge Road, Chester, NY ", "41.314926,-74.270134", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["Jim Smith", "12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ ", "41.041599,-74.019554", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Jones", "689 Fern St Township of Washington, NJ ", "40.997704,-74.050598", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],

];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  // alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found " + locations.length + " locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][2];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][3],
      address: locations[i][1],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][1] + "<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + locations[i][1] + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  $("#mdiv").click(function() {
    $("#side_bar").css({
      "z-index": 100,
      "top": "0px"
    });
    $("#panel").css("z-index", -100);
    $("#mdiv").css("display", "none");
  })

}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, 12);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, 12);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, 12);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
    closest.sort(sortByDist);
  }

  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)

}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);

        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' approximately ' + results[i].duration.text + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;" + results[i].address + "&quot;);'>Get Directions</a><br><hr>"

      }
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      $("#side_bar").css({
        "z-index": -100,
        "top": "25px"
      });
      $("#panel").css("z-index", 100);
      $("#mdiv").css("display", "block");

      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));


    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
table,
tr,
td {
  height: 100%;
}
.text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#side_bar {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 400px;
}
#panel {
  z-index: -100;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 400px;
}
#mdiv {
  z-index: 500;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 0px;
}
.mdiv {
  height: 25px;
  width: 2px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1;
}
.md {
  height: 25px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map" style="height: 100%; width:400px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="side_bar" class='text'></div>
      <div id="panel" class='text'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="address" type="text" value="Paramus, NJ" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();" />
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="mdiv">
  <div class="mdiv">
    <div class="md">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```