# two items in a row without resizing - flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple problem: I want to put a text and an image in one row. I tried with display flex but it always resizes the image, that's not what I want.

This is my html code:

```
 <span class="head_form">
     <h3>Neue Einkaufsliste</h3>
     <img src="img/close.png" alt="close button">
 </span>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.head_form{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

I also want to put the closing imgage at the very right in the box. It always looks like this:

[image]

It's probably quite easy to solve but I'm so confused by now. I'm thankful for any help :)

Comment: I guess they discuss it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611195/x-close-button-only-using-css

Comment: add `align-items: center` to `.head_form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="flex-layout">
  <div class="flex-item"><h3>Neue Einkaufsliste</h3></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><img src="img/close.png" alt="close button"></div>
</div>

.flex-layout{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: no wrap;
}

.flex-item img{
width: (**Fixed width**px)
}
```