# Center CSS X button

Tags: html, css

I have bee trying to do a close button using CSS in order to close a tag.
I have done this using a compination of a pattern described here: [Patterns for Closebuttons](https://www.htmhell.dev/20-close-buttons/), and a css only pattern for creating an X [Close Button using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611195/x-close-button-only-using-css).

Now to my question:
I can't figure out why the X is not entierly centered.
If I change the placement to 50% of whatever width I'm using for the lines it seemes fine, thus I come to the conclusion it has to have something to do with the width of the lines.

I'm writing here to see if someone could explain this to me.

```
'HTML
<button type="button" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="close"></span>
</button>

'CSS
button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(192,192,192);
  border: none;
  color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  /* right: 10px; */
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.close:before {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

I created a codepen for simplicity: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/SweCurium/pen/eYgobOW)

Comment: Everything looks fine but the lines just need to be positioned correctly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxiYj.png

Comment: You just need to negatively compensate half the width of those pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add flexbox to the `.close` class and you're ready to go

```
.close {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%; // 100% means that both lines will take the entire space
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

The width of the `.close:before, .close:after` CSS rule is actually letting both lines "expand" horizontally, starting from the center.

But, as they are being rotated, their starting position is not the same as if they were not rotated, so that's why their alignment becomes non-centered. You can inspect the item and you will see that the actual box has an empty space, which is the "rotated width" empty space.

Consider a x = 0 coordinate (0px from CSS box left margin)  which is the horizontal starting point of the CSS box; rotating elements will make content to start at x = ? (usually half of the content width)

You could solve this issue also by setting a negative `margin-left` with its value being half the `width`, but using flexbox will require much less maintenance (just imagine working with UI/UX guys telling you to change its dimensions)

Comment: Thank you, any idea why its not centered to begin with?

Comment: @PatrickBender please check my updated answer, I hope it will make things clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

Add This CSS `left:50%; margin-left:-10px;` on `.close:before, .close:after`

```
.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello there try to add this to your span class .close:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

You should not use right or left when your attribute is relative.

Comment: Thanks, missed that on the span just had it on the button.
Any ideas why its not centered to begin with?

Comment: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2021/17/3/1619615435-capture-d-ecran-2021-04-28-a-15-08-49.png

If you check the screen, your span is centered you can see it, but not your things inside of it.