# How to make a cross close sign in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have used a popup script so that popup appear on my screen when I load my html file now I want a close sign on the top right corner on the popup screen like in the picture shown below[image]

The code I have used is

("jsfiddle.net/sGeVT/10/")

this script code is an example of my code I have further modified it but the basic of the popup is same.
Hope you understand and can give solution.

Comment: see my updated answer. The last link will show you how to do it without images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Add a span with a `x` inside, `&times;` the best looking one IMO.

```
<span class="deleteMeetingClose">&times;</span>
```

(2) Set up some styles for it.

```
.deleteMeetingClose {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

(3) Add it to the jQuery code along with other close triggers.

```
$('#overlay, .deleteMeetingCancel, .deleteMeetingClose').click(function () {
    //close action
});
```

**Updated demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zj0yL9me/

```js
$('.deleteMeeting').click(function () {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#popupBox').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#popupContent').fadeIn('slow');
});

// added .deleteMeetingClose into the selectors
$('#overlay, .deleteMeetingCancel, .deleteMeetingClose').click(function () {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#popupBox').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#popupContent').fadeOut('slow');
});

$('.deleteMeetingButton').click(function () {
    $('#popupContent').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#deleteMeetingConfirmDeleted').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#overlay').delay(1300).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#popupBox').delay(1300).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#deleteMeetingConfirmDeleted').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    display:none;
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color:black;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 999;
}
#popupBox {
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    width:600px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #000000;
    border:5px solid #4E93A2;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#popupContent {
    display:none;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4E93A2;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.deleteMeetingButton {
    clear:both;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:90px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #5CD2D2;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.deleteMeetingCancel {
    clear:both;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:90px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #5CD2D2;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    content:"XXXX";
}
#deleteMeetingConfirmDeleted {
    display:none;
}
/* added code below */
.deleteMeetingClose {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Content Obscured By Overlay
    <button class="deleteMeeting">Delete</button>
</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="popupBox">
    <div id="popupContent">
        <i>Are you sure you want to delete this meeting?</i>
        <br />
        <span style="text-align:center;color:black;font-size:40px;">YO</span>
        <br />
        <button class="deleteMeetingButton">Delete</button>
        <button class="deleteMeetingCancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <div id="deleteMeetingConfirmDeleted">Meeting Deleted</div>
    <span class="deleteMeetingClose">&times;</span> <!-- <= added this line -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put in image element in your popup div

```
<img id="ClosePopup"  src="insert-image-url-here"/>
```

Then, style it with `position:absolute`. Also, make sure the popup div has `position:relative`

```
#ClosePopup{
 position: absolute;
 right:0px;
}
```

Finally, attach your click handler

```
$('#ClosePopup').click(function(){
   $('#overlay,#popupBox,#popupContent').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

See it working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGeVT/115/)

If you want a pure css solution without images, see
[Pure css close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019797/pure-css-close-button)

Comment: I want to do it without putting image and without writing a text and align it to right

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `span` element containing `×` char for the x, put some style and bind the click event to the popup close action:

### HTML

```html
<span class="cancel-icon" >×</span>
```

### CSS:

```css
.cancel-icon{
    float:right; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

### JS

```js
$('.cancel-icon').click(function () {
    //Close the popup  
});
```

Using your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sGeVT/118/